# Ошибка Run-Time Check Failure #2:

Tags: c++, c

После выполнения кода вибивает ошибку:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'x2' was corrupted.
```

Как решить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define RowX1 7
#define ColumnX1 9
#define RowX2 8
#define ColumnX2 6

void array(int x[][ColumnX1], int rows, int columns);
int Xm(int x[][ColumnX1], int rows, int columns);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int x1[RowX1][ColumnX1], x2[RowX2][ColumnX2];
    int z;


    puts("Масив XM1:\n");
    array(x1, RowX1, ColumnX1);
    puts("Масив XM2:\n");
    array(x2, RowX2, ColumnX2);

    z = (labs(Xm(x1, RowX1, ColumnX1)) + labs(Xm(x2, RowX2, ColumnX2))) / 2;
    printf("z = %d", z);

    return 0;
}

void array(int x[][ColumnX1], int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            x[i][j] = -150 + rand() % 301;
            printf("%5d", x[i][j]);
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
    puts("\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

int Xm(int x[][ColumnX1], int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j, min = x[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            if (x[i][j] < min)
                min = x[i][j];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, у вас

```
void array(int x[][ColumnX1], int rows, int columns);
```

а вы предаете ему то

```
array(x1, RowX1, ColumnX1);
array(x2, RowX2, ColumnX2);
```

хотя

```
int x1[RowX1][ColumnX1], x2[RowX2][ColumnX2];
```

они разные. То же и с вашей `Xm`.

Так что вы благополучно выскакиваете за пределы массива, ну, а дальше - UB со всеми последствиями...

Кстати, как C++, код вообще не скомпилируется, вы эту метку зря поставили. А как С - будут предупреждения, например, у VC++ -

```
test.c(28): warning C4048: разные индексы массива: "int (*)[9]" и "int [8][6]"
test.c(30): warning C4048: разные индексы массива: "int (*)[9]" и "int [8][6]"
```